# SPWebConfigModification and the SPContentService collection

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, spwebconfigmodification

I have created a class that parses an xml file and then adds the appropriate modifications to the web.config in my SharePoint 2010 web applications. When a feature is activated the proper mods are added to the web.config and when it is deactivated or uninstalled the mods are retracted.

In my xml I have about 9 nodes that are marked EnsureSection so I can be sure that some of the elements I need for example  and  are in the web.config. I do not retract
these nodes when a feature is deactivated since I don't want to interfere with someone else using those nodes in the application.

Today I was poking around with PowerShell and I noticed that when I get the web application contentservice and look at the WebConfigModifications collection in memory; the mods that are
for ensuring sections have been replicated in the collection. They have been replicated the number of times that I have activated the feature from the Central Admin.

I have code that wraps the adding of the mods so if they are already present in the collection I do not re-add them. I do not understand why the items that I have marked as
EnsureSection are being replicated in the collection. Does anyone know why those mods would
be getting multiplied like that?

Comment: Not that this comment is the least bit constructive, but this sounds like one of the problems people generally have with SPWebConfigModifications - it's duplicating of entries even when you tell it not to do so.

Comment: Indeed. I could not figure out how to stop this so we have switched over to a pure powershell solution for our entries. We are in a multi-tenant farm so we can't just wipe the collection each time which is what I was doing before.